# Filtering django queryset by text applying the diacritics

Tags: django, django-queryset, diacritics

I am trying to filter a queryset in python by a text

the model is:

```
models.Offer
       id = pk           
       description = text
```

I am trying to filter it like:

```
someText = self.shave_marks(someText)
offers = offers.filter(description__icontains=someText)
```

Where the shave_marks is replacing the special characters like: ç will become c.

The text in the database (in the description field) also has special characters, what I need is to "shave" the description text first then do the filtering.

Any help, thank you very much!!!

Comment: That is definitely the best option, since whether two strings are equal, depends on the collation, which is actually quite complex, and thus by changing some settings, it might no longer work.

Comment: the description should contain the someText or they could be equal, I really don't get what you mean :P, could you please elaborate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this ?

```
offers = [(x, x.description)) for x in offers.objects.all()]

required_offers = []

for key, value in offers:
    if someText in shave_marks(value):
        required_offers.append(key)
```

Comment: I am getting this error: TypeError: 'Offer' object is not iterable

Comment: the problem is in: for key, value in offer

Comment: edited, now it is a dict rather than a tuple. should be able to work key value

Comment: TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173911/discussion-between-ojas-kale-and-rodwan-bakkar).

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is, create a custom field extending charfield. have that field override method [get_prep_value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-python-objects-to-query-values)

I could not find a concrete example, but in theory this should work.

```
class SpecialField(models.CharField):
    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return shave_marks(shave_marks)
```

Comment: But in this case it will always remove special characters? I need to show the description text in the original languages in some cases and in other cases I need to do the filtering!

Comment: that would happen if you override to_python method. that makes changes before saving to database. get_prep_value makes changes while fetching from db. I believe.

Comment: What I understand is that I should (in the Offer model) replace the type of the description field from ChartField to SpecialField, in this case, whatever I retrieve from the database (the description) will be "shaved"???, sorry if I am not getting the idea :P

Comment: In some cases I need the original text (in Portuguese language) but in the case of filtering I need the shaved text!